# ftpwebrequest in timer error

Tags: c#, vb.net

Im trying to do a FTPWEBREQUEST in a timer but I get this error on `TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd`

```
Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.
```

can you help?

thanks

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

        Timer1.Stop()

        Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(""), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("", "")
        Dim response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

        Dim ResponseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
        Dim reader As New StreamReader(ResponseStream)

        'Console.Write(reader.ReadToEnd)
        'MessageBox.Show("Directory List Complete, status {0}", response.StatusDescription)


        'MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd)
        'MessageBox.Show(reader.ReadToEnd)

        TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
        TextBox1.Text = vbNewLine
        TextBox1.Text = vbNewLine

        ResponseStream.Close()
        reader.Close()

        response.Close()






        reader.Close()
        response.Close()


        Timer1.Start()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know your goal exactly and why you need a timer.

But I want to give you some advices for you coding practice:

You should not close (dispose) your streams twice. Use the `Using` statement for more clean and 
readable code. It also helps to release the resources early, even a exception is thrown.

```
Public Class Form1    

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load    

    End Sub    

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick    

        Timer1.Stop()    

         Dim request As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(""), FtpWebRequest)
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

        request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("", "")
        Using response As FtpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

            Using responseStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)


                    TextBox1.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
                    TextBox1.Text += vbNewLine 
                    TextBox1.Text += vbNewLine
                    ' Use the + for appending (set the textbox to multiline)

                End Using

            End Using

        End Using    

        Timer1.Start()    

    End Sub    
End Class
```

Comment: thanks - thats great - just one thing tat i noticed, If I add a new file to the directory while my forma app is running it does not show the new file - do you know why? thanks

Comment: which file you mean? From your FTP dir list or some local?

Comment: so if while the application is running and its polling the ftp location and showing the directory contents. if i copy a file into the folder with filezilla i would expect my applications text box to update while its running but it wont..thnaks for the help